# Bootstrap Carousel height to fit screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website for the first time and am get my hands dirty with bootstrap and css. I am using bootstrap carousel and using the basic carousel with 2 slides. However I am not able to style the height of the slides to the height of the screen. I tried adjusting the carousel height to 100% but it is not working right (extends way beyond the screen height). If I give a pixel height, like height: 500px; it works fine. But I want it to fit the entire scree. Any help on how I can achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid after-navbar">   
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row row-content">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-height" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
             <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
             <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner carousel-height" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active carousel-height">
              <%= image_tag("bg1.jpg", class: "img-responsive") %>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>BLAH </h2>
              </div>                        
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="#"><%= image_tag("bg1.jpg", class: "img-responsive") %></a>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>BLAH</h2>                        
              </div>
            </div>                    
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel {
  background: $bgDefault;
}
.carousel .item {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel .item img {
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/59900 might help

Comment: It looks like you've got a container fluid within another container fluid, the second will be redundant, all it is doing is adding padding on the sides

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put the height of the carousel at 100% height too, and then add 100% height to the body and html element so it would be:

```
.carousel{
   height:100%;
}
body, html{
   height:100%;
}
```

if this doesnt work then may be add:

```
.container-fluid.after-navbar{
    height:100%;
}

.row-content, .row-content > .col-xs-12{
    height:100%;
}
```